# Is it necessary to include Seder HaAvodah in the Musaf Repetition on Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur, song-poetry, musaf, chazarat-hashatz

As far as I understand, *piyyutim* (poetic additions to/replacements for certain *brachot* in public prayer) are optional/only a *minhag*, and that omitting all of them wouldn't be a problem.

On the other hand, Rabbi Hershel Schachter mentioned in a recent video ([here, from 1:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMT4Wq1OCCc&t=70s)) that the *Seder HaAvodah* (a *piyyut* describing the day's proceedings in the Temple — or rather, one of many different such *piyyutim*) in *musaf* of Yom Kippur is required, "*midina degemara*" (by Talmudic law). I know that the *Seder HaAvodah* was said during the time of the *gemara* (Yoma [36b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.36b.9?lang=bi), [56b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.56b.12?lang=bi); it wasn't in poetry then), but I don't see where it's described as required. Indeed, there are communities who don't say the *Seder HaAvodah* during the repetition, but instead say it afterward (although I know of no current community that omits it entirely, but ShimonS points out that Rambam and the old Aleppo rite omit it).

One possible source: Rav Amram Gaon describes the *Seder HaAvodah* [here](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7284&pgnum=359) as חובת היום (requirement of the day), but I think he's actually talking about the sprinklings and *viduy*, which are the requirements of Yom Kippur *in the temple*, and not the telling of the *Seder* in the *musaf* repetition. In any case, I wouldn't call Rav Amram Gaon's requiring this *piyyut* as being *midina degemara*, so I'm interesting in other (earlier) sources.

Is it really required, whether *midina degemara* or otherwise? If it is, what is the status of a "*musaf* service" that omits the *Seder HaAvodah* (both from the *musaf* repetition and afterward)? If it isn't, is there a strong a priori preference for including it, or can one omit it intentionally?

Comment: Which communities only recite it after the repetition?

Comment: @JoelK Baladi Teimanim, for example. Probably some other communities who usually remove *piyyutim* from the repetitions, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I know that followers of the Gra who do normally remove piyyutim still say the Avodah (and many of the other piyyutim of RH and YK) during the repetition.

Comment: Even if it's required, you can probably come up with something shorter than the standard piyut for shaas hadechak

Comment: How could it be required in the repetition and not the silent version? (Not that you couldn't say it in the silent version too, just that's certainly not commonly practiced.)

Comment: @DoubleAA We have such things: kedusha and birkat kohanim.

Comment: @magicker does seder hayom need a minyan to answer? It's straight musaf content not a separate mitzva put into the context of public prayer

Comment: @DoubleAA Not that I believe this, but: maybe it does?

Comment: 1. Seder HaAvodah is not mentioned by the Rambam, neither in Halachot nor in Seder HaTefila. 2. It is missing in Machzor Aram Tzovah (Aleppo) and the community did not say it for centuries until they accepted Spanish customs. 3. The paytanim felt free to make their own versions, which was not the case with obligatory parts of the tefilah.

Comment: @Shimon 3 is not correct

Comment: @ShimonS Thanks for pointing out Aleppo. As DoubleAA mentions, #3 is wrong: plenty of piyyutim entirely replace the obligatory parts of prayers (in fact, that was their original function).

Comment: Plenty paytanim indeed did so, for example Yose ben Yose for Mussaf of RH. But not all of them. For Seder HaAvodah this seems to go across the spectrum. See: https://www.amazon.com/Avodah-Ancient-Library-Literature-English/

Comment: @ShimonS What does "across the spectrum" mean here?

Comment: I mean from early EY paytanim (who were indeed very flexible) to Meshulam ben Kalonymus (in Italy/Ashkenaz) or Ibn Ezra (in Spain, where they were not very flexible with changing the obligatory parts). Even the Maharitz in Yemen didn't feel the need to defend the old piyut they used and accepted the change to the one used in Spanish machzorim (granted, in Yemen they said it after the chazara so it doesn't really matter).

Comment: It should be also noted that Rav Schachter follows here the approach of Rav Soloveitchik who sees Seder HaAvodah as part of Tefilas HaTzibur (as per Rav Chaim Brisker's understanding of chazaras hashatz) and therefore requires the shatz to say every word of the Avodah out loud (See Halachic Positions and Machzor YK Mesoras HaRav). I have not seen this approach by other poskim.

Comment: @ShimonS what is the point of a chazzan saying anything quietly? I don't understand. Everything he says is for the tzibbur. Maybe there are poskim who justify after the fact a chazzan who said something quietly, but surely that's just bedieved. I can't think of anything the chazzan should lechatchila say quietly. Either say it aloud or skip it.

Comment: I'm not talking from a halachic point of view but it is certainly the common practice in most Ashkenazi shuls that things that are also said by the tzibur (such as Selichos, or Brachos of Shma and Shma) are said by the Shatz rather quietly. It seems to me that saying parts of the Avodah quietly is the practice of vast majority of Ashkenazi minyanim. The Rabbis there do not protest (and most of the people are learning or reading something anyway).

Comment: @ShimonS At the end of the day, it seems you agree that some paytanim wrote piyyutim to replace obligatory parts of prayer. Thus, you cannot argue that since the seder ha'avodah is a piyyut, it cannot be obligatory.