What piyutim is one permitted to omit on Rosh Hashona and Yom Kippur
Is one permitted to omit piyutim on Rosh Hashonah and Yom Kippur in the night and day in the Ashkenazi machzor, as it is a tircha detziburah.

Related (even possible duplicate): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95155/15256 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/115255/15256

Keep in mind that different communities had different lists of piyutim, so Frankfurt a/M, for example, doesn't say "Yoreiti Biftzoti" as well as a number of other ones in shacharis for the first day of R"H, but never omits the silluk

I don't understand the question. If the custom is to say something then that's the custom. Are you asking which are the first ones to drop under exigent circumstances? Are you asking if shuls can change their customs willy-nilly?

@NoachMiFrankfurt But did they say "Yoresi Biftzasi"? :P

I'm organising a minyan for people who aren't bringing in their minhogim from other shuls.

@DoubleAA there are a couple of possible middle grounds to that. An obvious one is something might be in the siddur, but is not necessarily a custom. Could be that there is a category of piyut that could fall under "a custom, but it's still optional". Or it could be a situation where there is a problem related to identifying the correct custom. Is my shul a shul that skips the bit in the siddur that says "some congregations skip this", or not? Maybe these things are obviously silly to someone with advanced learning, but they could be reasonable questions that occur to thoughtful minds.

@RabbiKaii I don't understand most of what you said (other than the case of a new place with no custom)

@DoubleAA Maybe these things are nonsense* to someone with advanced learning, but they could be reasonable questions that occur to thoughtful minds.

@RabbiKaii They have to be coherent to be a reasonable question.

@yosefkorn Generally, customs in a new place ought be established by the rabbi. Is your question "which piyyutim are most important to include in a new shul's custom?" Is it "which elements of Edition X's service are customary additions as opposed to legal requirements binding even without a local custom?"

@DoubleAA, for whatever reason, I use Israeli-style transliteration on Mi Yodeya, but Ashkenazis IRL

There is no rabbi, it's a minyan for young people who would otherwise probably not go.

Personally I'd rather arrange a minyan that said more piyutim

@yosefkorn עשה לך רב Every minyan needs someone to decide halachic issues.

More importantly, this site can't answer for your specific case. But you can ask one of the more generalized questions I suggested above.

So I did some research and I found out that the shulchan oruch paskens that one should not add piyutim. So I guess that's my rabbi sorted.

@yosefkorn Rav Yosef Karo is the rabbi for your ashkenazi minyan?

First of all, we're talking about a minhag to add in liturgy. And then we look at the halocha which says not to say it. What's the problem. Should we halachicly allow minhag. Just because ashkenazi shuls do it, doesn't mean we should or it is the right thing.

@yosefkorn "And then we look at the halocha which says not to say it." One side of halocha says not to say it. The other side, brought by the Rema (רמ"א) in the shulchan oruch (O.C. 68:1 and O.C. 112:2), says that there is no prohibition in adding piyutim, even in the blessings of the Shema and in the Tefilah. Outside the Shema and the Tefilah, it may be permissible to add piyutim, even according to R. Yosef Karo.

Related: According to halacha, how should a shul's minhag be decided?

Chas veshalom! Avodas Hashem is not a tircha detzibura! It's a fundamental mitzvah!

So I did some research and I found out the shulchan oruch paskens that one should not say or add any piyutim.
The remah used to be silent when people would say it in his shul.
I found my rabbi.

This is incorrect

באופן כללי מובא ב"הלכה ברורה" שמחבר השולחן ערוך פוסק שאין לומר פיוטים בתפילה ולא בקריאת שמע, ולעומת זאת הרמ"א פוסק כפי מנהג האשכנזים שאין איסור בדבר ויש לומר פיוטים. בפועל ישנם בעניין זה מנהגים שונים בקהילות שונות.https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=46518

"The remah used to be silent when people would say it in his shul" The Ramah who did this was not R. Moses Isserles (רמ"א), author of the glosses to the shulchan oruch, representing where Askenazim differ from the rulings of the shulchan oruch, but was R. Meir Abulafia (רמ"ה), a contemporary of Ramabam, some 300 years before the writing of the shulchan oruch.

"So I did some research and I found out the shulchan oruch paskens that one should not say or add any piyutim." In the two places it paskens that (O.C. 68:1 and O.C. 112:2), the Rema (רמ"א) says there are those who say that there is no prohibition regarding this, and that such is the custom in all places to say them. Even your comment quotes, "ולעומת זאת הרמ"א פוסק כפי מנהג האשכנזים שאין איסור בדבר ויש לומר פיוטים".

We're still talking about a minhag. It's not a mitzvah.

@yosefkorn Minhag doesn't mean it's optional.

Minhogim and chumras are fine to do. They are not mandatory.  Like I said, its a minyan for  people who can't handle long davening. It's a tircha detziburah. It's also torture for a lot of Jews in other shuls, frum and less frum. Yiddishkeit is not about torturing people. Especially concerning something that isn't even mandated by halochah. Get your priorities right when it comes to halocha, minhag and chumras.

The question was not about omitting things in extenuating circumstances (eg for kiruv purposes where the people can't handle it)

"We're still talking about a minhag. It's not a mitzvah." Those aren't mutually exclusive. A minhag may obligate you to praise God in specific ways, but any beautiful prayer/praise is certainly a mitzvah.
